# Question on the inverse Mellin transform $p(x)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[-\xi(s)\,\frac{\zeta'(s)}{s\,\zeta(s)^2}\right]\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, probability-distributions, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Consider the function

$$p(x)=\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \Lambda(k) \left(\frac{2 \pi k^2}{x^2}-1\right) e^{-\frac{\pi k^2}{x^2}}\right)\tag{1}$$

where

$$P(s)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[p(x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty p(x)\, x^{-s-1}\, ds$$ $$=\pi^{-\frac{s}{2}}\, (1-s)\, \Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)\,\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\,,\quad\Re(s)>1\tag{2}$$

---

The residue formula for $p(x)$, which I believe converges for $x>0$, is

$$p_o(x)=\log(2 \pi)+p_{-2n}(x)+p_\rho(x)\tag{3}$$

where $p_{-2n}(x)$ and $p_\rho(x)$ defined in formulas (4) and (5) below are sums over the trivial and non-trivial zeta zeros respectively.

$$p_{-2n}(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-2 n} (-\pi)^n \left(\zeta'(-2 n)+n (2 n+1) \left(\zeta''(-2 n)+\zeta'(-2 n) (\psi^{(0)}(n)+2 \log(x)-\log(\pi))\right)\right)}{2 n\, n!\, \zeta'(-2 n)}\tag{4}$$

$p_\rho(x)=\sum\limits_{\rho} \left(\pi^{-\frac{\rho}{2}} \, \left(1-\rho\right)\, \Gamma\left(\frac{\rho}{2}+1\right)\, \frac{x^{\rho}}{\rho}\right)\tag{5}$

---

Note the similarity between formula (2) above and the term of the series in formula (5) above, whereas the term of the series in formula (4) above is more complicated due to the poles of the $\Gamma\left(\frac{s}{2}+1\right)$ function in formula (2) above.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates formula (5) above for $p_\rho(x)$ evaluated over the first $100$ pairs of non-trivial zeta-zeros which is largely dominated by the contribution of the first pair of non-trivial zeta-zeros. Note the magnitude of the oscillation in $p_\rho(x)$ seems to grow as $x$ increases.

[image: Illustration of formula (5)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of formula (5) for $p_\rho(x)$

---

> **Question**: Does the Riemann hypothesis predict a bound on the growth of the magnitude of the oscillation in $p_\rho(x)$ illustrated in Figure (1) above?

---

Figure (2) below illustrates formula (1) above for $p(x)$ (blue curve) seems to converge to $\log(2 \pi)$ (orange horizontal dashed line) as $x\to\infty$ which is consistent with the leading term in the explicit formula for $p_o(x)$ defined in formula (3) above.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (1) for p(x)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of formula (1) for $p(x)$

---

The function $p(x)$ defined in formula (1) above is an even function of $x$, but Figure (2) above originally seemed to suggest to me the function

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & x<0 \\
 \frac{1}{\log(2 \pi)}\,p(x) & x\ge 0 \\
\end{array}\right.\tag{6}$$

could potentially qualify as a CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) related to the distribution of the primes. But I now suspect the oscillation in $p_\rho(x)$ illustrated in figure (1) above causes $f'(x)$ to have an infinite number of $0$ crossings which also perhaps eventually leads to $f(x)$ having an infinite number of $1$ crossings.